# Disable pagination First and Last buttons

Tags: tabulator

When using tabulator and the pagination feature, I want to disable First and Last buttons.
I tried using the paginationButtonCount property, and set it to 3 instead of the default 5, but that didn't change anything.

Is there a way to accomplish that?

Also, is there a way to set the enablement/disablement of the pagination buttons on my own?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For solving this, I inspected how the default pagination html looked like.
Then, I used tabulator's footerElement configuration in order to prepare my own footer element:

```
footerElement: preparePaginatorElement()
```

The resulting method looks like this:

```
function preparePaginatorElement() {
    previousButton = document.createElement("button");
    previousButton.classList.add("tabulator-page");
    previousButton.type = "button";
    previousButton.role = "button";
    previousButton.ariaLabel = "Prev Page";
    previousButton.title = "Prev Page";
    previousButton.setAttribute("data-page", "prev");
    previousButton.disabled = true;
    previousButton.innerText = "Prev Page";
    previousButton.addEventListener("click", () => changePage(currentPage - 1, true));

    nextButton = document.createElement("button");
    nextButton.classList.add("tabulator-page");
    nextButton.type = "button";
    nextButton.role = "button";
    nextButton.ariaLabel = "Next Page";
    nextButton.title = "Next Page";
    nextButton.setAttribute("data-page", "next");
    nextButton.disabled = true;
    nextButton.innerText = "Next Page";
    nextButton.addEventListener("click", () => changePage(currentPage + 1, true));

    pageButton = document.createElement("button");
    pageButton.classList.add("tabulator-page"/*, "active"*/);
    pageButton.type = "button";
    pageButton.role = "button";
    pageButton.innerText = "1";
    pageButton.style.cursor = "default";

    const pagesSpan = document.createElement("span");
    pagesSpan.classList.add("tabulator-pages");
    pagesSpan.appendChild(pageButton);
    
    const paginatorSpan = document.createElement("span");
    paginatorSpan.classList.add("tabulator-paginator");
    paginatorSpan.appendChild(previousButton);
    paginatorSpan.appendChild(pagesSpan);
    paginatorSpan.appendChild(nextButton);

    const footerContentsDiv = document.createElement("div");
    footerContentsDiv.classList.add("tabulator-footer-contents");
    footerContentsDiv.appendChild(paginatorSpan);

    const footerDiv = document.createElement("div");
    footerDiv.classList.add("tabulator-footer");
    footerDiv.appendChild(footerContentsDiv);

    return footerDiv;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using remote pagination, you can hide the button in your ajaxResponse function.

```
ajaxResponse:function(url, params, response){
    document.querySelector('[title="Last Page"]').hidden = true;
return response.data;
```

Comment: I am using local pagination.